# VC++ 2012: "found using argument-dependent lookup" work-around?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, overloading, ambiguous, argument-dependent-lookup

It was probably asked, but I'm interested in how to make this code work with VC 2012:

```
#include <vector>

namespace ns {
   struct Obj { };
   template <class T> void swap(T& a, T& b) { }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::vector<ns::Obj> v;
   std::vector<ns::Obj>().swap(v); <-'std::swap' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
   return 0;
}
```

I have to use this ns namespace, and can't change it. It must be able to work without STL, and has its own swap(). How to properly use it together with STL though?

Comment: Actually it looks like a bug of MSVC, as g++ and clang++ do not call `ns::swap` at all. I'll try posting another possible solution.

Comment: it still works this way in VS2022. And such lookup seems to be an ancient feature - refer to [Argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl): _Argument-dependent lookup makes it possible to use operators defined in a different namespace_

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution for std::vector().swap(v):

```
namespace ns {
inline void swap(Obj*& a, Obj*& b) { }
inline void swap(Obj& a, Obj& b) { }
}
```

However, this not general fix since I can have something like this:

```
std::map<int, std::map<int, ns::Obj>> m;
m[0] = m[1];
```

Edit:

Here is another hack that works in the above case

```
namespace ns {
template <class T> void swap(T* a, T* b) { }
inline void swap(Obj& a, Obj& b) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef NS_USE_STL

#include <utility>

namespace ns {

using std::swap;

}

#else

// define your own swap

#endif
```